# Mingw64 linking against System32 binaries instead of SysWOW64

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling, mingw32, xuggler, mingw-w64

I have built a 3rd party library with Mingw64 (Xuggler a Java wrapper for FFmpeg) which produces a x86_64 binary. Unfortunately, this binary links against the 32bit versions of its dependencies. If I open it up in depends.exe, Kernel32.dll User32.DLL WS2_32.dll are all listed as dependencies. While this configuration may technically be valid, it certainly won't work on Java via JNI, since a 64-bit JVM will refuse to load 32-bit binaries. Is there anyway to force the liking to be done against the 64 bit system dependencies?

Comment: `kernel32.dll` and other system libraries may very well be 64-binaries. The `32` suffix is there for compatibility reasons only. Did you verify your executable is in fact a 32-bit executable?

Comment: I can confirm that under Windows 7 64bit, the *32.dll you're talking about are 64bit libraries. A strange issue I noticed is that doing - for example - `cp /c/System32/ws2_32.dll /c/mingw64/some/lib/libws2_32.dll` is breaking/converting the dll to 32 bit file (according to Dependency Walker - depends.exe)... While copying/renaming it through Windows Explorer keep it unchanged... Still weird. If anyone has an explanation...